# Borel-Cantelli lemma (a fixed string of zeros and ones of length $k$)

Tags: probability-theory, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I want to show the probability that a fixed string of head and toss of length $k$ appears when I flip a coin, is one.

I think to use a binary expansion of $\omega$ for $\omega \in [0,1]$;

I define $d_n(\omega)$ the **n**th binary digit and $a_i$ the digit of the string

So I have the event $$A_n=\{d_n(\omega)=a_i,......,d_{n+k-1}(\omega)=a_{i+k-1}\}$$

The teacher says the $A_n$ aren't independent so I can't use Borel-Cantelli Lemma 2.

But why aren't they independent?

Comment: To avoid independence, you want to avoid overlaps.  For example, If I tell you the first three flips are all heads, you know that the flips 2,3,4 are not all tails. If I tell you the first three flips are all heads, then it is more likely that flips 2,3,4 are also all heads (since we already know the result of flips 2 and 3).

Comment: But there is no need to use Borel-Cantelli here.  Just chop the timeline into disjoint frames of size $k$ each.  Then use the law of large numbers to compute the fraction of frames that have your desired pattern.

Comment: This question is related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1281769/

Comment: Sojourn times in a deBruijn graph can help answer the question if you want to consider overlaps.

Comment: I see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1281769/ why $A_r,A_{2r},.....$ are indipendent?